# Swift how to create complex folder structure in temp folder

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsfilemanager

I would like to create folder structure in the temp folder of the application.

Structure of the folders should be:

- iPhone

  - Intensity

    - Positive
    - Negative
  - Elipses

    - Positive
    - Negative
  - Composite

    - Positive
    - Negative

I am using `FileManager` to create directories.

```
class func createBaseDirectory() {

let filemgr = FileManager.default

let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

let docsURL = dirPaths[0]

let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("iPhone").path

do {
    try filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: newDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
}
```

But this way is not efficient.Because i should duplicate quite a lot of code snippets. Do Swift language have some more convenient ways how to create folder structure ?

Comment: Pass an array of folder names to the function, and use a loop to create each folder ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following in a Swift playground (same as Martin R suggested), seems to work fine:

```
import Foundation

let fm = FileManager.default
let baseUrl = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let subPaths = [
    "iPhone/Intensity/Positive",
    "iPhone/Intensity/Negative",
    "iPhone/Elipses/Positive",
    "iPhone/Elipses/Negative",
    "iPhone/Composite/Negative",
    "iPhone/Composite/Negative",
]

subPaths.forEach { subPath in
    let url = baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(subPath)
    do {
        try fm.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        print("path created: \(url)")
    } catch let error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

You could create an extension on NSFileManager using this code for reusability.